# How to change the value of MVVM property in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have been trying to solve the following problem for a very long time but unfortunately, I am unable to get it fixed.

I have a button which I want to disable it in another page **.cd**

**This is how my code looks like:**

```
<StackLayout>
 <Button Text="Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" Command="{Binding OnEnabledButtonClicked}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

  bool _isButtonEnabled;
  public bool IsButtonEnabled
  {
      get => _isButtonEnabled;
      set
      {
         _isButtonEnabled = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnabled));
      }
  }

  public Command OnEnabledButtonClicked 
  {
     get
     {
         return new Command( () =>
         {
            IsButtonEnabled = true;
         }
     }
  }

}
```

**And this is the class where I want to change the value of VM's button.**

```
public class Page1 {

  class page1() {

    InitializeComponent();

  }

  public void OnDisabledButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    /// IsButtonEnabled = false;

  }

}
```

I have already tried different ways but still no result.

**It would be a big help for me if someone provides me a solution for it.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Before I gave you an answer, I would like to point out few things.
It's common to suffix your command with Command : EnabledButtonCommand.
I can see that your command is async while you don't await anything. It's bad.

Why would you want to set IsButtonEnabled in the code behind instead of in the method executed by the command (in the ViewModel) ?

Where do you set the DataContext ? Do you use Prism or anything else to associate the ViewModel to your page's DataContext ? If you don't, you need to do this :

```
public class MyPage()
{
    private MyViewModel _viewModel = new MyViewModel();

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    public void OnDisabledButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.IsButtonEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

If your ViewModel was set in Xaml or elsewhere (while navigating, with Prism, etc)

```
public class MyPage()
{
    private MyViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;
    }

    public void OnDisabledButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myViewModel.IsButtonEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

A last word : if a button is not enabled, the command/click event won't be available to user until the button is enabled again.

You can test that with a button with its command binded to the given command and another button with IsEnabled binded to your boolean.

The code I gave may have things wrong as I answer in browser without using an EDI.

Comment: _"if user doesn't tap on your button, the command isn't instanciated [sic]. It will be instanciated [sic] only the first time it is 'get'."_ -- that is not true. The property value is retrieved during initialization of the binding that refers to it. It is simplest and best to just initialize the read-only property in the constructor. Beyond that, most of the rest of your answer is speculative; the OP didn't provide a good [mcve], so you can't really say _what_ would work at all, never mind suggest that either of your proposals are reasonable.

Comment: @PeterDuniho that's how you end up with a constructor of 1000 lines.

Yeah you are right about the instanciation, my bad. I was hit by the new which will return a new instance each time you bind to the command again. I guess it's time to go to sleep, its 2:37 am here and I spent the night on Flutter :)

Maybe use a property { get; } = new Command(); to keep a constructor clean. It becomes a mess once you have tons of dependencies to resolve, etc.
I will edit my answer to not mislead people who read this and also to ask if he has set the DataContext. Thanks for being careful !

Comment: If you have a view model with 1000 `ICommand` properties, you have a lot more wrong with your code than 1000 lines in the constructor.